# PHP elseif else

Tags: php

With the following code, I would like to plot the image sun.png when sky is clear, cloud when the sky is cloudy and variable in other cases...but something fails...I always get the image variable.png

```
<?php 
if($sky == "clear" ) {
  echo '<img src="images/sun.png" width="40">';
} 
elseif ($sky == "cloudy" ){
    echo '<img src="images/cloud.png" width="40">';
} 
else {
  echo '<img src="images/variable.png" width="40">';
}
?>
```

I consult the database using this code @Jack Goodman

```
$data_query = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'select * from `weather` where `data` = "2017-03-22" and (`num` = "1" or `num` = "2" or `num` = "3")');
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_query)){ ?>
```

**At the end I have solved it, my code had a mistake, the right code is**

```
  <?php 
if($data['sky']  == "clear" ) {
  echo '<img src="images/sun.png" width="40">';
} 
elseif ($data['sky'] == "cloudy" ){
    echo '<img src="images/cloud.png" width="40">';
} 
else {
  echo '<img src="images/variable.png" width="40">';
}
?>
```

Comment: What is yours `$sky` variable contains ?

Comment: If you always get the `else` block then your conditions are always `false`.  What does `$sky` contain?  Not what do you *think* it contains, but what *does* it contain?

Comment: add `$sky = 'cloudy';` before yours if statement and u will see that it works, so probably your `$sky` variable is empty

Comment: $sky is not empty, sometimes is clear, sometimes is cloudy, but always i get the image variable.png. I get $sky by mysql , this variable is in a database

Comment: can u post yours whole code with query to see where is problem exactly ?

Comment: @EnricAgudPique: `$sky` may not be *empty*, but if you're reaching that else block then it is definitely *not* `"clear"` or `"cloudy"` either.  If the only conclusion you can draw is that your code/data/etc. *must* be correct and that PHP's implementation of `if` conditions *must* be broken somehow, then nobody here can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere in the variable sky. I downloaded pictures and tested it with this code by changing the variable's value and it all works fine.

```
$sky = "cloudy";

if($sky == "clear" ) 
{
echo '<img src="sun.jpg" width="40">';
} 
elseif ($sky == "cloudy" ) 
{
echo '<img src="cloud.jpg" width="40">';
} 
else 
{
echo '<img src="variable.png" width="40">';
}
```

Show me the code where you get the sky's value please.

[image: Sunny]

[image: Cloudy]

[image: Variable]

Comment: I consult the database using this code @Jack Goodman

$data_query = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'select * from `weather` where `data` = "2017-03-22" and (`num` = "1" or `num` = "2" or `num` = "3")');
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_query)){ ?>

Comment: Can you please echo out the variable $sky in your code just before it goes into the first if statement and let me know what it says?

Comment: Thank @Jack Goodman for your help, at the end I have found the mistake as I show in the code

Comment: Pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be clearer using a switch statement, then you could have a catch-all for unmet conditions and use it to debug your issue:

```
switch($sky){
    case 'clear':
        echo '<img src="images/sun.png" width="40">';
        break;
    case 'cloudy':
        echo '<img src="images/cloud.png" width="40">';
        break;
    default:
         echo '$sky is something unknown';
         var_dump($sky);
         break;

}
```